# Find and replace a function name and also edit its parameters

Tags: command-line, bash

I have function `TRIAL_FUNC(a, b, c)` called multiple times in multiple C files.

I need to find every occurrence of this function in multiple C files and replace it with `trial_func(a, b, c, b)`, adding a 4th parameter with value of `b`.

The parameters are not same in all the calls of this function in the files. Some examples can be taken as: `TRIAL_FUNC(x, sizeof(y), z)`, `TRIAL_FUNC(sizeof(d), 45, e)`. As can be seen, there is no same pattern in the parameters.

Assuming the files are kept within the same directory, can someone help me write a shell script (bash) to achieve this task?

Comment: You should really use an IDE with refactoring tools. Regex-based substitutions depend on your specific code format and can easily break.

Comment: Re-write the function `TRIAL_FUNC` to just call `trial_func` with the given parameters instead.

Comment: @PerlDuck Can't. Its a standard Safe-c library function in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, heed [danzel's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114779/find-and-replace-a-function-name-and-also-edit-its-parameters/1114787?noredirect=1#comment1840724_1114779):

> You should really use an IDE with refactoring tools. Regex-based substitutions depend on your specific code format and can easily break.

With that said, you can do a regex substitution with `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/TRIAL_FUNC(\(.*\), \(.*\), \(.*\))/trial_func\(\1, \2, \3, \2\)/' *.c
```

Explanation:

- `-i.bak` - Edit the file "in-place", i.e. saving changes, but make a backup with a .bak extension first
- `s/x/y/` - Substitute `x` with `y`
- `\(\)` - This is a match group
- `.*` - Zero or more characters
- `\1` - Insert the first match group
- `*.c` - All .c files in the current directory

Examples:

- Here's the code you mentioned:

  ```
  TRIAL_FUNC(a, b, c)
  TRIAL_FUNC(x, sizeof(y), z)
  TRIAL_FUNC(sizeof(d), 45, e)
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  trial_func(a, b, c, b)
  trial_func(x, sizeof(y), z, sizeof(y))
  trial_func(sizeof(d), 45, e, 45)
  ```
- And here's incompatible code:

  ```
  TRIAL_FUNC(
      foo, bar, baz,
      )
  TRIAL_FUNC(a,b,c)
  other_func(TRIAL_FUNC(a, b, c), TRIAL_FUNC(a, b, c))
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  TRIAL_FUNC(
      foo, bar, baz,
      )
  TRIAL_FUNC(a,b,c)
  other_func(trial_func(a, b, c), TRIAL_FUNC(a, b, c), b)
  ```

  You could write a regex that could account for these, but it's not worth the effort.

*This is based in part on [Kristopher's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114782/301745), and partly on my last answer, which is now deleted.*

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the regex for this task will not be worth the effort. The above mentioned command will suffice. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Prashu Excellent! Happy to help. If my answer helped, please click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/TRIAL_FUNC\(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\)/trial_func\(\1, \2, \3, \2\)/' *.c
```

- `sed` is a stream editor
- `-i` means edit "in place" - i.e. it will modify the files directly (make a backup first!)
- `s/` means "substitute" where `s/x/y/` replaces all x with y
- The rest is regular expressions:

  - `\(` is used to match a literal `(` since it's a special regular expression character
  - `([0-9]+)` is used to match a number and save it's match as a "group"
  - `\1`, `\2`, and `\3` are used to access that matched "group"

Comment: How does this match `TRIAL_FUNC (x * x, y * y, 2 * z % (m + n))`?

Comment: @Kristopher Ives use `[^,]*` instead of `[0-9]+` to match anything until the next `,`.

Comment: Use whatever regex you want, OP asked to match integers, so I did =)

Comment: Hmm... did you test this? Your `s` command doesn't seem to be properly terminated, and `+` is only a quantifier in ERE mode (`sed -E` or `sed -r`) I think?

Comment: Did OP's code have integer literals before? Cause right now it's just names - `a, b, c`

Comment: When I run this, an error comes, saying : sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @steeldriver How can I terminate the s command in the above script?

Comment: @PrashuPratik Sorry I forgot a `/` at the end, which I've fixed

Comment: @wjandrea OP didn't originally ask for the ability to match any integer *expression* which, technically, isn't being done via `[^,]*` either.

Comment: @KristopherIves Thanks for the support. The s command is terminated now. But its not working still. This error comes : -e expression #1, char 70: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: doing this with `sed` (or any other regex substitution) will not work if there are function calls with multiple arguments in the argument list, e.g.: `TRIAL_FUNC(f1(x, f2(y, z)), b, c)`.